# Access 97 Outer join issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have two tables I want to join.

Table A has one column, named "Week", and contains 52 rows: 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.
Table 2 has three columns, named "Name", "Week", and "Total", and contains 10 rows:

```
'Bob', 1, 1
'Bob', 3, 1
'Joe', 4, 1
'Bob', 6, 1
```

I want to join these together so that my data looks like:

```
NAME|WEEK|TOTAL
'Bob', 1, 1
'Bob', 2, 0
'Bob', 3, 1
'Bob', 4, 0
'Bob', 5, 0
'Bob', 6, 1
```

As you can see, a simple outer join. However, when I try to do this, I'm not getting the expected result, no matter what kind of join I use.

My query below:

```
SELECT a.WEEK, b.Total
FROM Weeks a LEFT JOIN Totals b ON (a.Week = b.Week and b.Name ='Bob')
```

The result of this query is

```
NAME|WEEK|TOTAL
'Bob', 1, 1
'Bob', 3, 1
'Bob', 6, 1
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You dont specify what those columns are in your sample data.

Comment: @JNK - Cant believe we're in 2012

Comment: @JonH Added...and yes, Access 97. Stuck with it unfortunately (I'd upgrade if I could!)

Comment: what did you expect ? (mmmh I already heard that sentence, did I ?)

Comment: @Mansfield I just looked at your access query.  Change it to this:

Comment: `SELECT a.WEEK, IIF(ISNULL(b.Total), 0, b.Total) AS Total
FROM Weeks a LEFT JOIN Totals b ON (a.Week = b.Week) WHERE b.Name = 'Bob'`

Comment: Notice I added the `IIF` check, you need to handle the null cases, that is why you are missing the rows you are after.  Without handling the null cases, access dumps them..and so does SQL Server...

Comment: Added the IIF, still nothing...

Comment: Mansfield think about it for a moment.  If bob didnt participate in week 2 what would you expect the query to return?  Of course if you take the where condition out it works because that would show you that in week 2 total 0 Name NULL...

Comment: No, it doesn't show me that. It doesn't show any entry for week two at all, that's the problem; and that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.Name, b.Week, b.Total
  FROM Totals AS b 
 WHERE b.Name ='Bob'
UNION
SELECT 'Bob' AS Name, a.Week, 0 AS Total
  FROM Weeks AS a 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
                      FROM Totals AS b 
                     WHERE a.Week = b.Week
                           AND b.Name ='Bob' );
```

Answer (score 3):

I know its access but your join is incorrect.  Here we go in sql server..same concept just look at the join condition:

```
--dont worry about this code im just creating some temp tables

--table to store one column (mainly week number 1,2..52)
CREATE TABLE #Weeks
(
  weeknumber int
)

--insert some test data
--week numbers...I'll insert some for you
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(4)
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO #Weeks(weeknumber) VALUES(6)

--create another table with two columns storing the week # and a total for that week
CREATE TABLE #Table2
 ( 
  weeknumber int,
  total int
 )

--insert some data
INSERT INTO #Table2(weeknumber, total) VALUES(1, 100)
--notice i skipped week 2 on purpose to show you the results
INSERT INTO #Table2(weeknumber, total) VALUES(3, 100)

--here's the magic
SELECT t1.weeknumber as weeknumber, ISNULL(t2.total,0) as total FROM 
#Weeks t1 LEFT JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.weeknumber=t2.weeknumber

--get rid of the temp tables
DROP TABLE #table2
DROP TABLE #Weeks
```

Results:

```
1   100
2   0
3   100
4   0
5   0
6   0
```

Take your week number table (the table that has one column:

`SELECT t1.weeknumber as weeknumber`

Add to it a null check to replace the null value with a 0.  I think there is something in access like `ISNULL`:

`ISNULL(t2.total, 0) as total`

And start your join from your first table and left join to your second table on the weeknumber field.  The result is simple:

```
SELECT t1.weeknumber as weeknumber, ISNULL(t2.total,0) as total FROM 
#Weeks t1 LEFT JOIN #Table2 t2 ON t1.weeknumber=t2.weeknumber
```

**Do not pay attention to all the other code I have posted, that is only there to create temp tables and insert values into the tables.**

Comment: @Mansfield: It sounds like you have some problem with the actual data, check your weeks table make sure you have the numbers you expect.  Just do a select from that table and post it.  Then do a dump from the other table and post it.  Combine the two together using the exact same syntax I posted.  Show us these in your posts.

Comment: I'm really quite sure my data is fine - I've checked it several times. If I run your query in SQL server it works fine, but not in access.

Comment: @Mansfield I just ran this same thing in Access 2010 and it worked perfectly fine.  Of course I changed it from using temp tables to regular tables.  But it came back right with this: `SELECT t1.Field1 as weeknumber, IIF(ISNULL(Field2),0,Field2) as total FROM 
Weeks t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Field1=t2.Field1`

Comment: @JohH Access 2010 has a lot of features access 97 does not. I also didn't mention I also have a filter (see answer below)

Comment: @Mansfield well you have to admit i put forth the effort :).

Comment: @Mansfield your changes in your question dont look to be right. You have AND b.Total='Bob'???  Try to change it to a WHERE clause to be more readable Use my query and at the end add `WHERE b.Total=100` or whatever.

Comment: @JonH I fixed it. I was hesitant about including the whole thing because I find it tends to be a distraction. At any rate, I have added it now. I have tried filtering the name both in the ON section and in a where clause, neither have worked.

Comment: @Mansfield, make this easier on yourself and us.  Insert 3-5 records in the weeks table.  Insert 3-5 records in the 2nd table.  Show your querty and the results within access.  Then show us what you had expected.  I think this is an issue with your data not the query.

Comment: @JonH: The data is fine, once again. I have 52 records in the weeks table, number 1-52 exactly. I have 4 records in my second table as I showed in the OP. If I don't specify the name = bob everything works fine, but with that clause it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track, but just needed to use a left join. Also the NZ function will put a 0 if total is null.

```
SELECT Totals.Person, Weeks.WeekNo, Nz(Totals.total, 0) as TotalAmount
FROM Weeks LEFT JOIN Totals 
ON (Weeks.WeekNo = Totals.weekno and Totals.Person = 'Bob');
```

EDIT: The query you now have won't even give the results you've shown because you left out the Name field (Which is a bad name for a field because it is a reserved word.). You're still not providing all the information. This query works.

**Another Approach: ** Create a separate query on the Totals table having a where clause: Name = 'Bob'

```
Select Name, WeekNo, Total From Totals Where Name = 'Bob';
```

and substitute that query for the Totals table in this query.

```
Select b.Name, w.WeekNo, b.total
from Weeks as w 
LEFT JOIN qryJustBob as b
on .WeekNo = b.WeekNo;
```

Comment: I do have a filter which I neglected to mention - removing it made everything work fine, unfortunately I need it. I added it as you suggested but no luck...

Comment: @Mansfield what do you mean you have a filter?  You mean a condition in your WHERE clause?  Please post this information in the question to get better help.

Comment: @JonH I've edited again to better reflect what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @Mansfield - Why didnt you start with that as a question, you left out a lot of information that changes everything.  You should always include all details so you get the correct answer.